# Session Id Is coming null in android from server

Tags: android, retrofit

I have created a login activity when user enters their username and password and then press the login button. From the server, if the login is login is successful then I am checking all the data from the server .
Except for the session-id remaining all the data is coming from the server. But session id I am getting null

**RetrofitInstance.java:**

```
public class RetrofitInstance {

    private static Retrofit retrofit;
    private static final String BASE_URL = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXxx";

    /**
     * Create an instance of Retrofit object
     * */
    public static Retrofit getRetrofitInstance() {

        final HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor  = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor .setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        CookieHandler cookieHandler = new CookieManager();
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addNetworkInterceptor(interceptor )
                .cookieJar(new JavaNetCookieJar(cookieHandler))
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        if (retrofit == null) {
            retrofit = new retrofit2.Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .client(client)
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

**LoginActivity.java:**

```
Call<Login> call1 = service.GetLoginList(operation,username,generatedKey);

/**Log the URL called*/
Log.wtf("URL Called", call1.request().url() + "");

call1.enqueue(new Callback<Login>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(Call<Login> call1, Response<Login> response) {
    if(response.isSuccessful() ) {

        Login login=response.body();
        String success=login.getSuccess().toString();

        if(success.equals("true")){
            String result= login.getResult().toString();
            Log.i("result", "result" + result);
            String head =response.headers().get("Set-Cookie");
            Log.i("head", "head" + head);
            String sessionId=login.getResult().getSessionId();
            Log.i("sessionId", "sessionId" + sessionId);
            String userId=login.getResult().getUserId();
            Log.i("userId", "userId" + userId);
            String version=login.getResult().getVersion();
            Log.i("version", "version" + version);
            String vtigerVersion=login.getResult().getVtigerVersion();
            Log.i("vtigerVersion", "vtigerVersion" + vtigerVersion);



            if(username.equals("admin")&& pass.equals("Password!1")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Login Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Username and Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }


        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid Username and Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Call<Login> call1, Throwable t) {
    Log.d("error",t.getMessage());
    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Something went wrong...Error message: " + t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

Login.java:

```
public class Login {

    @SerializedName("success")
    private String success;

    public String getSuccess() {
        return success;
    }

    public void setSuccess(String success) {
        this.success = success;
    }

    public GetLoginList getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(GetLoginList result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    @SerializedName("result")
    private GetLoginList result;
}
```

**JSON Response:**

```
 sessionId: sessionIdnull
 userId: userId19x1
 version: version0.22
 vtigerVersion: vtigerVersion7.1.0
```

Comment: Could you please add code of Login class.

Comment: Why `Call<Login>` & `Response<Login>` and the calling class is also called `Login`? To me this somehow provides limited sense and the server-side code might also be relevant. Are you sure, that it even starts a server-side session? The output is neither JSON, nor does it match the `Log.i()` statements.

Comment: @Rajnishsuryavanshi Added login class

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes the output is JSON

Comment: @jyothigen this is plain text and not JSON and this log is missing some lines. Can you login, when posting from a HTML form? In general, this all is "wtf", because the client doesn't even consider the login result. There's `service.GetLoginList` and there's `GetLoginList`; this is all very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY` won't intercept any headers, which doesn't make the debugging any easier; better use `HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.HEADERS` instead. Assuming that the server actually starts a session... then one should be able to get it's ID with:

```
String sessionId = response.headers.values("Set-Cookie").toString();
```

And when presenting it again, the header should be `"PHPSESSID=" + sessionId`.

The default idle timeout is 15 minutes, which needs to be handled, too.